# Updating the ListView in a Fragment from a Dialog in FragmentActivity(using a ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `FragmentActivity` (main) which creates 3 `Fragments` and also a menu. Pretty straight forward, and from the examples in the Android SDK.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbh = new DBHelper(this);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}

// code //


@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new DaySectionFragment(Main.this, dbh);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new WeekSectionFragment(Main.this, dbh);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new FoodListSectionFragment(Main.this, dbh);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new AboutSectionFragment();
                break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }
//more code
```

From the menu in the main activity I have a dialog with an editText. The value from this textfield is suppose to be stored in a database, which works fine, and also pop up in the listview in the fragment (not i ListFragment, but a fragment with a listview in it). The simple way would be to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the ListView adapter. However I can't do that.

This is the fragment with the ListView:

```
public class FoodListSectionFragment extends Fragment {
private Context context;
private DBHelper dbh;
private ArrayList<FoodData> listItems = new ArrayList<FoodData>();
private FoodAdapter adapterFoodList;
private AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo adapterInfo;
private ListView lvItems;

public FoodListSectionFragment() {
}
public FoodListSectionFragment(Context context, DBHelper dbh) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dbh = dbh;
    //setTag("FoodListFragment");
}
public void updateList(){
    adapterFoodList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.food_list, null);

    listItems.clear();
    listItems = (ArrayList<FoodData>) dbh.selectAllFood();

    adapterFoodList = new FoodAdapter(context, R.layout.list_row_food, listItems);

    lvItems = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.listFood);
    lvItems.setAdapter(adapterFoodList);
    adapterFoodList.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return myView;
}
}
```

Here is where I'm trying to update the ListView, although this won't work.

```
dialogAddFood = new Dialog(Main.this);
            dialogAddFood.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_food);
            dialogAddFood.setTitle(R.string.menu_add_food);
            dialogAddFood.setCancelable(true);

            Button btnSave = (Button) dialogAddFood.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText edtFood = (EditText)dialogAddFood.findViewById(R.id.edtFood);
                    RatingBar ratingGrade = (RatingBar)dialogAddFood.findViewById(R.id.ratingGrade);
                    RatingBar ratingDiff = (RatingBar)dialogAddFood.findViewById(R.id.ratingDiff);

                    if(edtFood.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                        dbh.insertFood(edtFood.getText().toString(), (int)ratingGrade.getRating(), (int)ratingDiff.getRating());
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Maträtt tillagd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //FoodListSectionFragment f = (FoodListSectionFragment)Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FoodList");
                        //f.updateList();

                        ListView l = (ListView)mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2).getView().findViewById(R.id.listFood);
                        FoodAdapter a = (FoodAdapter)l.getAdapter();
                        a.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    dialogAddFood.cancel();
                }
            });
            Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogAddFood.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialogAddFood.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialogAddFood.show();
```

Help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the line:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2)
```

doesn't return the `Fragment` at position 2 from the `ViewPager`, it **creates** a new `Fragment` for that position and calling update methods on this `Fragment` instance will obviously not make any changes as this `Fragment` isn't attached to your `Activity`(is not the visible one).

Try to look for that `Fragment` using the `FragmentManager` like below and see how it goes:

```
// ...
Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Maträtt tillagd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//FoodListSectionFragment f = (FoodListSectionFragment)Main.this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FoodList");
//f.updateList();
FoodListSectionFragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.theIdOfTheViewPager + ":2");
if (fr != null && fr.getView() != null) {
    fr.updateList();
}
```

Comment: That worked! Awesome! I just had to typecast the GetSupportFragment().findFragm... to FoodListSectionFragment.

Comment: But something is kind of weird. The list wont update directly, I have to swipe the pager a few times.

Comment: @Lubis The list doesn't update immediately even if you are at the page with the list(so the list is visible)?

Comment: @Lubis The behavior is normal because your adapter is based on some data from the database. The problem is that your adapter doesn't see(can't see) the newly inserted item in the database so the call to `notifyDataSetChanged` is useless. On the other hand when you go two steps right/left the `ViewPager` will destroy the view for the list fragment and when you come back the `onCreateView` will be called again and the database will be queried again.

Comment: @Lubis You could requery the database in the `updateList` method and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` or you could pass it the newly inserted item, add it to the adapter directly and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.